# What is the right way to reinstall from source after package was installed via apt?

Tags: installation, python, debian, compiling

I have a python package previously installed via apt(by default). Now I want to install new version and compile it manually from the sources with all the required modules.

How can I do that? I suppose that

```
apt-get purge python
```

And then install from sources is not possible because python have lots of dependencies and will uninstall all of them in this case.

What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to look at the command `sudo apt-get build-dep python` which will install all the build dependencies, but not the package itself.

Comment: I could be wrong but doesn't this install the build dependencies and not neccessarily the runtime dependencies? I mean, you would want this to build python but would it satisfy all the required packages of a python binary?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't tried it with python, but I haven't had problems in the past. At the very least, it'll save a heap of searching and compiling :)

Comment: this is a good approach, you still have to troubleshoot additional module stuff.  my experience was with ruby/ffmpeg/mplayer/other.  not all modules are considered critical in the base build...so they don't get pulled in with build-dep, but it's a faster start

Answer (score 0):

From your question I may not have understood what you are up to do. Please forgive me if I was wrong. In any case **you don't want to purge python** as much of Ubuntu depends on it.

To install an updated application (written in python) from source you most likely don't need to compile it as it can be run in the python interpreter provided with Ubuntu. When it comes to dependencies you may have to install them manually: check with the documentation that comes with your application.

In case the program update includes a DEB file you can perform the update conveniently with your preferred package manager.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't really need to purge your python installation, you just have to make the Ubuntu default version and the source compiled version live together peacefully.

To achieve that just **compile the source in your home folder** or, if you want to install for all users, user another installation prefix ( e.g. /usr/local/ instead of /usr/ )

Obviously only one python should be set in the system PATH ( and that should be the default one ).

Then to run a python script with the new version ( useful if you want to use python 3.0 while Ubuntu has 2.x installed ) just type:

```
/usr/local/bin/python myscript.py
```

also you can create a symlink of the new python to /usr/bin and call it /usr/bin/python30.

Hope this helps :)